# Does the order of checking whether a string is null or empty matter?

Tags: c#

For my programming exam I had to defend code I had written. One of the lines are:

```
if(app.Logourl == "" || app.Logourl == null)
```

He asked me whether there was a difference between null and an empty string. I told him that the difference was that `null` means its not pointing to anything, so it's not instantiated, but the empty string is.

After the exam I walked up to him and asked him if I was correct, since I saw a funny look on his face. He told me that it's true they're different, but the order in which I checked the values was incorrect.

Now a few days later I believe there's nothing wrong with the order. Am I correct?

**TL;DR**

is

```
if(app.Logourl == "" || app.Logourl == null)
```

equivalent to

```
if(app.Logourl == null || app.Logourl == "")
```

Comment: Instead of that use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` ;)

Comment: Farhad is right, of course. Other than that, for micro-micro-optimization, put the condition which you think will most often be true first, to have short-circuit evaluation skip the last check in more cases.

Comment: As others have pointed out, it's all the same in your actual case. However, I'd suggest to go with the route your teacher suggested and get used to always checking for `null` first. In many practical cases, as pointed out in the answers, it *will* matter and starting with the `null` check will simply reduce your errors in the long run. Wherever the environment offers a specialized function like `IsNullOrEmpty()`, use that instead of course, but you'll use the same pattern in lots of other cases, too, where you need to code the checks manually.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's OK the way you did it, because the overload of `==` for `System.String` calls [`String.Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hkt4325(v=vs.110).aspx), which allows `null`s.

This is not universal, however: if you wanted to check string length instead of using `== ""`, your first code snippet would be in trouble:

```
if(app.Logourl.Length == 0 || app.Logourl == null) // <<== Wrong!
```

while the second one would be fine:

```
if(app.Logourl == null || app.Logourl.Length == 0) // <<== Correct
```

The reason for this is short circuiting in the evaluation of `||` and `&&` operators: once they know the result (`true` for `||`, `false` for `&&`) they stop evaluation. In the second snippet above, if `app.Logourl` is `null`, the second half of the expression will be ignored, hence `app.Logourl.Length` would not throw a null reference exception.

**Note:** In recognition of checks like this happening all over the place, C# class library [offers a convenience method for doing this check](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(app.Logourl)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: To your first statement I can add the comment that all overloads of the `==` operator defined by the C# specification, including lifted operators on nullables, and all additional overloads of `==` defined by the BCL, will allow (i.e. not throw) one or both operands to be `null`. A user could introduce an overload of `==` that throws, but I guess that would be breaking a "contract" on how `==` is to be implemented.

Answer (score 2):

```
    private static bool IsNullOrEmpty(string s)
    {
        return s == null || s == "";

        /*
         Lets look behind the scenes here:
         =================================
        IL_0000: ldarg.0   => load s on the evaluation stack   
        IL_0001: brfalse.s IL_000f => GoTo label 'IL_000f' if loaded argument is null

        IL_0003: ldarg.0    => load s on the evaluation stack  
        IL_0004: ldstr ""   => load constant string "" to the evaluation stack
        IL_0009: call bool [mscorlib]System.String::op_Equality(string, string)
                              => Call String.Equality(string,string) with s and "" 
                                 loaded to the evalutation stack
                                 that will pop the two values compare them for equality and load the result.
                                 to the evaluation stack.                                     

        IL_000e: ret  => Return to the caller with equlity result on the evauation stack.

        IL_000f: ldc.i4.1 => Load constant value 1(4 byte which will represent "True") to the evaluation stack
                             and return to the caller.In our flow it's the case when s is null.
        IL_0010: ret 

         In Summary:
         ===========
        1.) IL instructions total code size 17 bytes.
        2.) Best case scenario execution path => 2 IL instructions.
        3.) Worst case scenario execution pat => 8 IL instructions.

        */
    }

    private static bool IsEmptyOrNull(string s)
    {
        return s == "" || s == null;

        /*
         Lets look behind the scenes here:
         =================================
         IL_0000: ldarg.0  => load s on the evaluation stack   
         IL_0001: ldstr "" => load constant string "" to the evaluation stack
         IL_0006: call bool [mscorlib]System.String::op_Equality(string, string)
         IL_000b: brtrue.s IL_0012

         IL_000d: ldarg.0 => load s on the evaluation stack   
         IL_000e: ldnull  => load constant null on the evaluation stack 
         IL_000f: ceq => Pop two loaded values compare and push the result back on the evaluation stack
         IL_0011: ret

         IL_0012: ldc.i4.1 => Load constant value 1(4 byte which will represent "True") to the evaluation stack
                             and return to the caller.In our flow it's the case when s is null.
         IL_0013: ret 

          In Summary:
         ===========
        1.) IL instructions total code size 20 bytes.
        2.) Best case scenario execution path => 6 IL instructions.
        3.) Worst case scenario execution path => 10 IL instructions.
     */

    }
```

## Conclusion:

Judging only by the IL emitted code 
 "if(app.Logourl == "" || app.Logourl == null)" 
 is "microptimization" better performance wise :)

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't matter (in your case).

One thing to know though, is that boolean operators `&&` and `||` short-circuit, which means if you have `a || b` and `a` is `true`, then `b` is not evaluated.

For example,

```
app.Logourl == null || app.Logourl == ""
```

If `app.Logourl` is `null`, then `app.Logourl == ""` is never even evaluated.

In your case, there's no real difference whether you check one or the other. first or the other first. If there checks were different, it could matter.

For example,

```
app.Logourl == null || app.Logourl.Equals("")
```

If you did the other order, you would get an exception if `app.Logourl` is `null`, since you can't call member functions of null references.

---

Though I'd use `String.IsNullOrEmpty(app.Logourl)`, which is the standard lib.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a comment.

In usual situations it won't matter. But there can be side effects. Here is a simple example to learn from:

```
static class Program
{
    static string Logourl
    {
        get
        {
            Console.WriteLine("getter runs");
            return null;
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        if (Logourl == "" || Logourl == null)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This program will write:

```
getter runs
getter runs
```

If you swap the order of the checks, `getter runs` will only print once. If you change the property to `return "";`, it will be opposite.

Using `string.IsNullOrEmpry(Logurl)` will always retrieve the property exactly once, of course.

Answer (score 0):

when I'm sure that my object is a `string` I always prefer the following:

```
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(yourString))
    {
        // this string is null or empty
    }
```

or this:

```
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(yourString))
    {
        // this string is null or empty (or got only a space)
    }
```

Comment: Note that if you are *not* sure if it is a string or not, i.e. if the declared type (compile-time type) is `object` or an interface that `string` implements, saying **`obj == ""`** should give a compile-time warning. It is dangerous because it checks for reference equality. Sometimes there are more than one instance of `string` which is empty.